# Theta characteristics of surfaces and theta functions

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, theta-functions

A theta-characteristic of a Riemann surface is commonly defined as a spinor bundle, i.e., a holomorphic line bundle whose square is the canonical line bundle. These are in a natural one-to-one correspondence with spin structures on the surface, i.e., $2^{2g}$ ways to assign a winding number modulo $4\pi$ to each of homology generators $A_1,\dots,B_g$, represented as simple loops.

On the other hand, I'm assuming that the name *theta-characteristic* comes from the correspondence with (half-integer) characteristics of Riemann theta function. So, given a symplectic homology basis $A_1,\dots,B_g$, a choice of $\left(\begin{matrix}\varepsilon\\ \delta\end{matrix}\right)=\frac12\left(\begin{matrix}\varepsilon_1,\dots,\varepsilon_n\\ \delta_1,\dots,\delta_n\end{matrix}\right)$ with $\varepsilon_i,\delta_i\in\{0,1\}$ should give rise to a bundle as above via the theta function $\theta\left[\begin{matrix}\varepsilon\\ \delta\end{matrix}\right]$.

**Q1: What is this correspondence explicitly?**

It seems to be standard that if the characteristic is odd, we can construct a holomorphic section of (the corresponding?) spinor bundle as
$$
\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{g} \partial_{z_i}\theta\left[\begin{matrix}\varepsilon\\ \delta\end{matrix}\right](0)\cdot \omega_i}.
$$where $\omega_i$ are Abelian differentials of the first kind. I don't understand, though, how to figure out the corresponding spin structure. Also, if the characteristic is even, in *Hejhal, Dennis A.*, [**Theta functions, kernel functions, and Abelian integrals**](https://doi.org/10.1090/memo/0129), Mem. Am. Math. Soc. 129, 112 p. (1972). [ZBL0244.30016](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0244.30016)., the Szegö kernels for the spinor bundles are constructed using theta-function. However, from Hejhal's point of view, the theta-characteristics corresponds to a character rather than spin structure, because he uses a reference spin structure provided by the Klein prime form.  Figuring out the right characteristics proves cumbersome.

**Q2 It appears that the Klein prime form gives, in a sense, a distinguished spin structure on a marked Riemann surface. What is it explicitly, and in which sense is it distinguished?**